# Adding single dimension float array values

Tags: c#, arrays, dicom, addition, evil-dicom

I have two questions regarding the Evil Dicom library.

I know with the floats function, all of the pixel data is contained as float elements in a one dimensional array. My question here is how can I add up the individual elements to get one value?

After I have multiplied a black and white mask with the original image, how can I then add up the non-zero values in the image? Do I also use the floats function to get the data as an array and then add up the array elements? If not, how can I add up the pixels in the image from top left corner to bottom right corner?

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like you would like the Stack Overflow community to do your research for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no special functionality in the Evil DICOM library for these operations, but there is always LINQ.

If you are looking for the sum of all pixel elements:

```
var imgMtx = new ImageMatrix("image.dcm");
var sum = imgMtx.Image.Sum();
```

If you are looking for the sum of the non-zero values:

```
var nonZeroSum = imgMtx.Image.Where(val => val != 0.0f).Sum();
```

If you are looking for the average value, simply replace `Sum` with `Average`.